# Maven m2 Repository: Making it OBR

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bnd, obr

I'm having an issue with my Maven Repository, I'm trying to get the BNDTools plugin for eclipse to work with my local m2 repository. But it claims that my m2 Repository is not an OBR repository, and so cannot be used for OBR resolution.

Apparently, the Maven-Bundle-Plugin should generate OBR data, but we (team) noticed that the repository.xml wasn't up to date with all the files in the repository, so we tried a workaround with apache karaf cave to rebuild the XML file, but i fear this is where I've gone wrong.

I realise this seems like an illogical workaround, but i guarantee you, in the setup we have, this seemed like the easiest way to go forward.

So my question to you is:
How can I get my repository.xml file to be rebuilt with all the OBR data. Or failing that, how can setup my m2 repo to be an OBR compliant repository.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I have realised, I can use maven-bundle-plugin's 'bundle:index' function to solve this issue. Hopefully this will help anyboybody else with the same issue.

Documentation [here][1]


  [1]: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.7/doc/site/index-mojo.html

Comment: Add this as an answer to your question and - when the time period expires - accept it. This will make it obvious to everyone what the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

maven-bundle-plugin has an "index" goal that can rebuild your repository.xml file.